# Angular NgBootstrap Modal How to listen to backdrop click

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

My use case would be, when I open the modal, a form will appear, while the user fill up the form, the user suddenly click on the backdrop, so the default behavior would be, the modal would be closed.

However, I want to listen on that event because I want to show a modal when the user accidentally click on backdrop which tells that "**DO YOU WANT TO SAVE CHANGES?**" something like that which generally tells that the form is **touched and dirty**.

I've read the documentation, and other sources, which tells on the shows something like this

```
modalRef.result.then((data) => {
      // on close
    },
    (error) => {
      // on error/dismiss
});
```

How do I pass or know that when I clicked on backdrop, the modal which holds the form has been **marked touched or dirty** so that I could display another modal informing the user for confirmation something like "YOU HAVE UNSAVED CHANGES"

I'm looking for like in Angular Material Dialog they have something like **afterClosed subscribe** method.

Thanks in advance. Please tell if I miss some code or details to provide.

Comment: did you try beforeDismiss callback?

Answer (score 0):

@Aakash Garg Thanks mate.

```
addOpenEntry(): void {
    const openEntryRef = this.modalService.open(OpenEntryComponent, {
      size: "lg",
      beforeDismiss: async () => {
        const dirtyForm = openEntryRef.componentInstance.form1.dirty;
        if (dirtyForm) {
          return await this.confirmationDialog();
        }
        return true;
      }
    })
  }




async confirmationDialog() {
    let payload = {
      dialog_title: "Unsaved Changes",
      dialog_msg: "You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to discard all your changes?",
    }

    let modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmDialogComponent)
    modalRef.componentInstance.data = payload;

    let result = await modalRef.result
    return result;
  }
```

The above code is what I have ended up writing and meet my use case. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

See the code for the very firs example in the docs: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

```ts
import { ModalDismissReasons, NgbDatepickerModule, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-basic',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgbDatepickerModule],
  templateUrl: './modal-basic.html',
})
export class NgbdModalBasic {
  closeResult = '';

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' }).result.then(
      (result) => {
        this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
      },
      (reason) => {
        this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
      },
    );
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ng-template #content let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Stuff can go here
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>

<hr />

<pre>{{ closeResult }}</pre>
```